# Why poor casting causes ActivityNotFound Exception in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, activitynotfoundexception

I recently came across an exception while writing a program and it took me a lot of time to debug simply because I was given a wrong exception by the compiler.

Here's my activity code:

```
 private var mCheatMap = HashMap<Int, Boolean>()

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)

    mCheatMap = savedInstanceState?.getSerializable(KEY_CHEATER) as HashMap<Int, Boolean> ?: HashMap<Int, Boolean>()
}
```

During runtime, my app crashed and when I looked into the logs, it said `ActivityNotFound` exception and in suggestion, it said maybe I didn't declare the activity in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

Everything seemed to be error free from my side when suddenly I, by chance, made my `mCheapMap` variable casting into a safe cast and everything started to work perfectly. e.g.:

```
 private var mCheatMap = HashMap<Int, Boolean>()

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)

    mCheatMap = savedInstanceState?.getSerializable(KEY_CHEATER) as? HashMap<Int, Boolean> ?: HashMap<Int, Boolean>()
}
```

Now I have a few confusions:

1. Why the compiler gave me the `ActivityNotFound` exception while I was having a casting issue?
2. Why using the safe cast operator solved the problem because even without the safe cast operator, my casting was correct?

Comment: @user2340612 that's the issue, the exception I only get was ActivityNotFound exception which is really out of sense. P.S. thank you for clearing my second question.

Comment: Maybe the `ActivityNotFound` might be explained by the fact that the `ClassCastException` is thrown in the Activity's `onCreate`, hence the creation does not succeed and the Activity cannot be found by the runtime. But that's only my guess, I may be wrong

Comment: This looks more like a null pointer exception than a class cast exception...I may be wrong.

Comment: The OP said that using the safe cast solved the issue, which should not be the case for a NPE. Plus, with the safe call operator (`?.`) and the elvis operator, `null` values are handled "safely" (unless the NPE happens somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you should get a `ClassCastException`, if the issue is about the wrong casting (by the way it's not the compiler that throws the exception, but the runtime. The compiler/LINT should warn you about an "unchecked cast", though).

Concerning your second question, the safe cast will return `null` in case of an unsuccessful cast, which makes you fall in the "else" branch of the elvis operator (`?:`), so you will create a new empty `HashMap<Int, Boolean>` and assign it to your `mCheatMap` variable. That doesn't happen in your first example since the failing cast throws an exception instead of simply returning `null`, so the "else" branch of the elvis operator can never be executed (you should get another warning by the compiler/LINT for this).